# system.xml in Xamarin studio not working

Tags: c#, xml, xamarin

I still haven't found a post with this exact issue, so I'll write a new one and hope for the best.

I have the following code to continue in my current C# tutorial, and Xamarin Studio is throwing me an error, stating

> "The type or namespace 'Xml' does not exist in the namespace 'System'.
>   Are you missing 'System.Xml' assembly reference?"

I've included "using System.Xml;" in my top portion like I think I should, but keep getting the error.

Any help would be much appreciated, the tutorial has been going so smoothly thus far.

Here is the code as it stands now...

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;

namespace ParsingXml
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      XmlReader xmlReader = ...
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the System.XML dll as a reference to your project.

Comment: I've tried adding "using System.Xml.dll;" and get the same error message. Any other possibilities?

Comment: right click on References in your Project and "Add Reference".  "using" just includes a namespace, it does not add a reference to your project

Comment: thanks for the clarification. in the Project tab, "Edit References" is shaded and unavailable. i'm not sure how to right-click on the project, as there is only the one window open, being the current .cs file.

Comment: Aha! in the "View" menu, after changing from "Code" to any of the other views, I was able to access the References and add System.Xml. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

After much searching, I was able to add the assembly reference by doing the following:

1. Click the "View" menu.
2. Choose on any other view type than "Code" (I chose "Design", but the others work too).
3. In the pane on the left, find the project folder you are working on, and dropdown to find the "References" folder icon.
4. Right-click on the "References" folder icon, and choose "Edit References".
5. Scroll down the list and mark the checkbox next to "System.Xml" (or any others you may need).

Solved!